# C# premake name clash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, premake

I'm moving some C# code over to premake and have encountered a problem related to name clashes during the build :

My premake solution looks like this :

```
workspace "Test"
configurations { "Debug", "Release"}

-- output locations
location("Intermediate/" .. _ACTION )
objdir ( "Intermediate/" .. _ACTION .. "/obj/%{cfg.buildcfg}/" )
targetname "%{prj.name}_%{cfg.buildcfg}"


project "Test"
    language "c#"
    kind "ConsoleApp"

    files
    {
        "**.cs",
        "**.xaml",
    }


    filter {}
```

And I end up including 2 offending files :

- TestFolder1\Test.cs
- TestFolder2\Test.cs

each with different namespace however they both compile to the same folder, and as such i get a MSB3105 compiler error stating the source file \Intermediate\vs2010\obj\debug\Test.g.cs was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter.

Any ideas how i can get the output debug files to keep the relative folder paths so that I can avoid these name clashes ?

I thought i could use the files.relpath token, however that's not valid for the objdir..

Thanks,